# Solve max length or precision with Progress using Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, openedge, progress-db

I'm using spring batch, and I need to query data from a legacy system, which uses the progress database.

However I am with this exception java.sql.SQLException: [DataDirect][OpenEdge JDBC Driver][OpenEdge] Column Ag-Obs-conf in table PUB.Agenda has value exceeding its max length or precision.

I was able to partially solve this problem using a SUBSTR in the select, but I need all the data from the database.

And I can not in any way change the database.

Can anyone give me an idea how to solve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OpenEdge database stores all data as variable length.  Applications  very commonly "overstuff" fields beyond the declared "SQL Width" attribute which is what is causing the error that you see.

Prior to OpenEdge 11.6 using dbtool is the standard way to adjust SQL width. It is fast, safe and effective:

http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P24496

Starting from OpenEdge version 11.6 a new database startup parameter was introduced:

-SQLWidthUpdate ON

that can automatically fix the SQL width of character datatypes.

More information about this new feature can be found here:

https://community.progress.com/community_groups/openedge_rdbms/f/18/t/19534

There are also some options in 11.6+ to automatically truncate returned data if that is what you prefer:

http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/How-to-enable-Authorized-Data-Truncation-in-a-JDBC-or-ODBC-connection/p

Comment: It will probably work, but I do not have any access to the database. By code, can I work around this problem?

Comment: You would ordinarily ask the DBA to run  dbtool -- it should be a routine procedure anywhere that SQL is used  with an OpenEdge database.  If the local admins refuse then you can work around it with your SUBSTR approach or, if the db is 11.6 or better by following the JDBC config instructions in the last link.